# Why does my code duplicate the text of a file?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am using Java to read the text from a file.  Here is my code:

```
public void readCurrentPage(){
    FileInputStream file = null;
    BufferedInputStream buff = null;
    int readByteValue;
    Exception lastShownException = null;
    boolean errorShown = false;
    boolean readOnce;

    try{
        errorShown = false;
        file = new FileInputStream("/Volumes/Storage Drive/eclipse/workspace/Nicholas Planner/bin/data/test.txt");
        buff = new BufferedInputStream(file,8*1024);
        while (true){
            readByteValue = buff.read();
            if (readByteValue == -1){
                break;
            }
            System.out.print((char) readByteValue + " ");

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        if(errorShown == false && lastShownException!=e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was an error: \n"+e, "Error!", 1);
            e = lastShownException;
            errorShown = true;
        }

    }finally{
        try{
            errorShown = false;
            buff.close();
            file.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(errorShown == false && lastShownException!=e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was an error: \n"+e, "Error!", 1);
                e = lastShownException;
                errorShown = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the text of the file:

```
test
This is cool!
```

When ever I read the file using the code above, this is what I get:

```
t e s t 
 T h i s   i s   c o o l ! t e s t 
 T h i s   i s   c o o l !
```

Why does my code duplicate the text of the file?

Comment: Your function looks fine. The problem might be where you call that function

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  I assume by function you mean method?  So using this code in a method would differ from using somewhere else?  How could I use it outside of a method?

Comment: @paulsm4 the `System.out.print()` is for printing the read char, but it looks his calling it twice or else the `t e s t` woudln't be printed in front of `c o o l !`.

Comment: Cin316, I think he meant that wherever you're calling "readCurrentPage" might be the problem.

Comment: @Cin316 yes, function is another word for method

Comment: This is the code I use to call readCurrentPage(): `public void drawBlankPlanner(Graphics g){
  
  g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  Utili.drawThick3DRectangle(g, 10, 10, 580, 655, 4);
  
  FileReader read = new FileReader();
  read.readCurrentPage();
  
  
 }`  The method is not called in the constructor of either class.

Comment: You guys are right!  It is being called twice.  But why?  I'll take a look at it.  Thanks!

Comment: Why did I get a downvote on this?  I'm just wondering because I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your favorite debugging tool, step through the code one at a time. One thing that I'm thinking it could be is you're calling the method twice (which is why using the debugger could help. It would also help you isolate the problem). This can happen if your method is called as a result of a swing event like a jList value changed event or something like that (those always get me). Good luck!

I'm not sure if you need to use that method for any paticular reason, but you might also try [this method](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/IOHelper.java#L66) from the [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper):

```
  /**
   * Takes the file and returns it in a string
   *
   * @param location
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static String fileToString(String location) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(location));
    return readerToString(fr);
  }

  /**
   * Takes the given resource (based on the given class) and returns that as a string.
   *
   * @param location
   * @param c
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static String resourceToString(String location, Class c) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = c.getResourceAsStream(location);
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
    return readerToString(r);
  }

  /**
   * Returns all the lines in the scanner's stream as a String
   *
   * @param r
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static String readerToString(InputStreamReader r) throws IOException {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = r.read(buf)) > 0) {
      sw.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    r.close();
    sw.close();
    return sw.toString();
  }
```

Comment: how's this related to OP's problem?

Comment: How does it not? I was under the impression that OP's problem was reading text from a file. That's what my answer strives to do...

Comment: OP problem is not about reading the file but reading the file twice. As he already commented, he was calling the method twice.

Comment: I gave my answer to a possible issue in that regard, as well as an alternative method if that was not the problem. I don't think I did anything wrong in my answer...

Comment: He can read the file, plus the file may be not in the classpath like you're suggesting ("/Volumes/Storage Drive/eclipse/workspace/Nicholas Planner/bin/data/test.txt"). Try to focus in the problem, then improve the actual solution.

Comment: I see no way to improve my answer, but if you think there is a better answer, go ahead and give your own. It looks like my answer "you're calling the method twice" is correct as has been indicated in the comments. Is it a problem that I gave an alternative in addition to an answer? My intentions were pure. I'm only trying to help :)

Comment: This is correct.  I used Eclipse (my IDE) to debug it, and found I was calling the method twice.  Oops!